# laravel how to access child row groupwise different parent

Tags: php, laravel

I have table structure like this

```
product 
 id 
 name 
 price

spec_master
     id
     name

product_spec
    id
   spec_master_id
   product_id
   label
  value
```

i have created model for this table structures. And also defined relationship as per documentation. I want to access specifications label-value pair group by spec_master.

is it possible using eloquent relationship ?

output structure like `product->spec_master->specification`

i have did this

**EDIT**

```
     $specmasters = SpecMaster::whereHas('specifications', function ($query) use($productid) {
                $query->where('product_id',$productid);
            })->with(['specifications'=>function($query) use ($productid) {
                    $query->where('product_id',$productid);
            }])->get();
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @madalinivascu i have edited with my try , it is giving output what i thought but i think i am going in right way

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Why not using laravel relations between `product` and `spec_master` ? then relation between `spec_master` and `specification`